# DES-ECS encryption in Java and decryption in PHP (decrption returns false)

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

I have to decrypt a pass phrase that was encoded in Java using

```
    byte[] phraseBlock = [-9, -101, -14, -63, 26, 127, -128, 121];
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] encryptedPhaseBlock = cipher.doFinal(phraseBlock );
```

Now after encrypting this it is send to my PHP code

> **Hex encryption phraseBlock = F79BF2C11A7F8079**
>
> **Hex encrypted encryptedPhaseBlock = A8B0E35246430D25**

```
    openssl_decrypt(hex2bin('F79BF2C11A7F8079'), 'DES-ECB', hex2bin('A8B0E35246430D25'))
```

After doing this i get false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "byte[] phraseBlock" means, but if You try like this:

```
bin2hex(openssl_decrypt(hex2bin('F79BF2C11A7F8079'), 'des-ecb', hex2bin('A8B0E35246430D25'), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA + OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING));
```

You get result

```
f699257c6ec30770
```